# Joda - the right way to get daylight savings independent times

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I'm working on some alarm functionality and I'm using Joda to calculate the millis for each alarm time. I have some utility methods, like:

```
 public static DateTime getNextDateTimeWithHourMinute(int hour, int minute) {
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    DateTime then = now
            .withHourOfDay(hour)
            .withMinuteOfHour(minute)
            .withSecondOfMinute(0)
            .withMillisOfSecond(0);

    return then.isBefore(now) ? then.plusDays(1) : then;
}
```

which calculates the next occurence of some hour and minute for me. Problem is, if we try to get, for instance, 2:00 am which of March 10, then we'll get a

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal instant due to time zone
>   offset transition: 2013-03-10T07:00:00.000

I know that in this case that time simply doesn't exist, but is there is a simple way to determine that between there's some transition occuring between `now` and `then` and then automatically make corrections. Obviously the corrections depend on your use case. In my case, I'd like it to be so that if the clock is falling back between now and then that I get a DateTime object delayed by an hour. In other words, if the user set an alarm for 3 am, for example, and then the clock moves backward around that time, that the alarm will fire when the clock time reads 3 am (which is now an hour later). Sorry for rant, hope this question makes some sense.

Comment: You're messing with the wrong 'type' in the library - use a [LocalTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) or [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) instead (using `LocalTime.toDateTimeToday()` or `LocalDate.toDateTime()` or `DateTime.toLocalTime()` or something).  Strictly speaking, an alarm shouldn't be dealing with the 'exact' time, anyways, due to DST (and timezones) - you should be constructing them from the 'local' values.  What should happen if the alarm would go off during the 'missing' hour?

Comment: Great points @Clockwork-Muse. I'm gonna look into switching types. I'm not sure how this will help me reason about/avoid these types of errors. Doing something like  `LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate().withMonthOfYear(3).withDayOfMonth(10);
        LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime().withHourOfDay(2);
        DateTime dateTime = localDate.toDateTime(localTime);` will still result in an error.

Comment: Constructing a `LocalDateTime()` and then using `DateTimeZone.isLocalDateTimeGap(...)` should be able to find them.  Also, `DateTimeZone.getMillisKeepLocal(...)` seems to be 'gap safe', in that it returns the 'next available' time for a timezone from a given 'local' value.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thanks a lot. But how do I get an instant from a LocalDateTime to pass to getMillisKeepLocal?

Comment: Also, if isLocalDateTimeGap returns true, how can I figure out which way the transition is going to, i.e. backwards or forwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lie through your teeth about the date/time zone of your alarm.  Eg:

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate().withMonthOfYear(3).withDayOfMonth(10);
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime().withHourOfDay(2);
DateTime dateTime = localDate.toDateTime(localTime, DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC.getMillisKeepLocal(DateTimeZone.getDefault(), dateTime.getMillis()));

System.out.println(dateTime);
System.out.println(dt);
```

Which in my case prints out:

```
2013-03-10T02:09:42.333Z
2013-03-10T03:09:42.333-07:00
```

(I live in Washington)

*However*, I think it's better to use something on the order of:

```
DateTime.now().toLocalDateTime().isBefore(new LocalDateTime(2013, 3, 10, 2, 0));
```

Which is more, erm, semantically correct.

Comment: What's your point about the isBeforeNow part? What were you trying to illustrate there?

Comment: The `.isBefore()` part is allowing me to say, "Hey!  Is the current instant in time (wherever on the planet I am) before this arbitrary date/time combination (that doesn't reflect timezone)?".  Conceptually, this is what you're actually dealing with: is this instant in time, translated for where I am, before a 'time-zone agnostic' date/time combination I've specified?